# How to create exception from another class

Tags: java, exception

I know how to create an exception, but I want to intentionally "break" another class.

Let there be two classes X and Y.

If X is running, how can I create an exception that causes the console to output an exception from Y?

Thanks!

~Java preferred

Edit:
Apparently +MarsAtomic and +Murat K. cannot comprehend English correctly. I asked to throw the exception from ANOTHER class, not the class that is running. I do not understand how people can live in society with such a deficient level of reading comprehension.

Comment: `throw new Exception`

Comment: `throw new RuntimeException();`

Comment: Apparently +MarsAtomic and +Murat K. cannot comprehend English correctly. I asked to throw the exception from ANOTHER class, not the class that is running. I do not understand how people can live in society with such a deficient level of reading comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
throw new RuntimeException();
```

or

```
String exceptionMsg = "Error";
throw new RuntimeException(exceptionMsg);
```

--

```
public class X
{
   public X()
   {
      Y.CreateException();
      //or
      Y.CreateException("Error");
   }
}

public class Y
{
    public static void createException()
    {
         throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public static void createException(String msg)
    {
         throw new RuntimeException(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I meant the third one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let there be:

```
public class thisIsAnException extends Exception{

    private Class source;

    public thisIsAnException(Class source){
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void setSource(Class source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(){
        return "Oh no, there is an exception in: " + source.getName();
    }
}

public class Y {

    public Y(){
        try {
            X instanceX = new X();
        } catch (thisIsAnException ex) {
            ex.setSource(this.getClass());
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            Y instanceY = new Y();
    }
}

public class X {
    public X () throws thisIsAnException{
        throw new thisIsAnException(this.getClass());
    }
}
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: I just can not understand what you did here